# Ethernet header from recvfrom is not as expected

Tags: c, network-programming, ethernet

I am writing some network packet sniffing code in C (running on an Ethernet LAN). While attempting to print out the Ethernet header, I've run into a bit of confusion. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame#Preamble_and_start_frame_delimiter) the first 8 bytes consist of the preamble and a delimiter and the next 6 are the MAC destination address.

However, when I actually run my code, I see that in the bytes I get from the recvfrom call, the initial 8 bytes (preamble and delimiter) are missing. In other words, I can start reading the destination address from the first byte itself.

Here is the relevant part of the code

```
char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
struct addrinfo servinfo;

servinfo.ai_family = PF_PACKET;
servinfo.ai_socktype = SOCK_RAW;
servinfo.ai_protocol = htons(ETH_P_ALL);

int fd = socket(servinfo.ai_family, servinfo.ai_socktype, servinfo.ai_protocol);
int plen = recvfrom(fd, buffer, BUFFERSIZE, 0, &caddr, &clen);
int c = 0;
printf("Destination Address: %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\n",buffer[c], buffer[c+1], buffer[c+2], buffer[c+3], buffer[c+4], buffer[c+5]);
printf("Source Address: %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\n",buffer[c+6], buffer[c+7], buffer[c+8], buffer[c+9], buffer[c+10], buffer[c+11]);
```

This prints the correct destination address, whereas I should have gotten the correct result by printing after skipping the first 8 bytes in the buffer.

What am I missing here, or doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This prints the correct destination address, whereas I should have
>   gotten the correct result by printing after skipping the first 8 bytes
>   in the buffer

The preamble is a very low-level concept, **handled strictly by the NIC**. It's not even visible to the OS, let alone returned by `recvfrom`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you point me towards any links/books for this? Most standard networking textbooks I have referred to don't have anything on this - as I found out now, obscure - point.

Comment: @talonx I can't think of any textbook for this. It's just something I wondered about a few years ago and someone told me (and showed me in a   Unix kernel).

Comment: @talonx Check out documentation on libpcap and tcpdump for learning about general stuff like this. My rule of thumb is that any packet info that isn't available to libpcap/tcpdump won't be available to me. If there's something you see that libpcap/tcpdump is able to do that you are not sure how to do, it's a lot easier to ask a question on a forum and say something like "I would like to do x; libpcap does x, how would I do x like libpcap does?"

Comment: @2to1mux Good rule of thumb!